# How to keep PIG job log file when it is successful.

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I noticed that when there is an error in running a PIG script, a log is generated and kept. But when there is no error, the log file is removed. Is there a way to keep the log file even when the job is successful?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default errors (e.g: script parsing errors) are logged to `pig.logfile` which can be set in `$PIG_HOME/conf/pig.properties`. If you want to log status messages too, then prepare a valid `log4j.properties` file and set it in the `log4jconf` property.

E.g: rename log4j.properties.template to log4j.properties in $PIG_HOME/conf and set the followings:

```
log4j.logger.org.apache.pig=info, B

# ***** A is set to be a ConsoleAppender.
#log4j.appender.A=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
# ***** A uses PatternLayout.
#log4j.appender.A.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
#log4j.appender.A.layout.ConversionPattern=%-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n

# ***** B is set to be a FileAppender.
log4j.appender.B=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
#log4j.appender.B.File=/home/user/pig-distrib/logs/pig_success.log
log4j.appender.B.File=/home/user/pig-distrib/logs/pig.log
log4j.appender.B.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.B.layout.ConversionPattern=%-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n
log4j.appender.B.Append=true
```

When using Pig v0.10.0 (r1328203) I found that a successful pig task doesn't write the job's history logs to the output directory on hdfs.
(`hadoop.job.history.user.location=${mapred.output.dir}/_logs/history/`)

If you want to have these histories by all means then set mapred.output.dir in your pig script in this way:

```
set mapred.output.dir '/user/hadoop/test/output';
```

Comment: I'm never clear on whether these changes impact the local pig interpreter that generates the Hadoop jobs, or the tasks that run the job.

Answer (score 0):

Once the log4j.properties file is prepared, open the pig.properties file and uncomment the following:

log4jconf=$PIG_HOME/conf/log4j.properties

Answer (score 0):

*Bumping old thread*

Easy way is to redirect output

```
pig -f pig-file 2> xyz.log  -- this will give just the logs
pig -f pigfile &> xyz.log -- logs + stdout(dumps)
```